# SQL Join between two tables excluding some fields

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, spring-boot, join

I have two tables Customer and Beneficiary, the relation between them is ManyToMany,
the generated table customers_beneficiaries contains the Id of Beneficiary and the Id of Customer
i want to get the list of customers with a given beneficiary_id

```
SELECT * from customer c 
Full OUTER JOIN customers_beneficiaries cb 
ON c.id= cb.customer_id
WHERE cb.beneficiary_id=8;
```

But the result iam getting contains the two fields of customers_beneficiaries table (customer_id && beneficiary_id)
How can i exclude them from the result
Thank you .

Comment: LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. FULL gives INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON is part of your OUTER JOIN ON. After an OUTER JOIN ON a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING needing some column(s) of the right/left/2 [sic] table(s) to be not NULL removes rows with introduced NULLs, leaving only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". Needing a non-NULL right/left column "turns FULL into RIGHT/LEFT". You have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:(In case you can change `id` column name in customer table to `customer_id`)

```
SELECT c.* from customer c 
Full OUTER JOIN customers_beneficiaries cb 
USING(customer_id)
WHERE cb.beneficiary_id=8;
```

`USING` Clause is like `ON` Clause which takes list of columns on which joining of table has to be done but those columns have to exist in both tables. The columns used in join operation appears only once in output.

Comment: Its better if you provide table structure of both the tables with required columns in your desired output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244249/discussion-between-nishant-gupta-and-mortadha-bouallagui).

Comment: See my comment on the question. Its code & this code return the same as if they used RIGHT JOIN.